# Find all pairs such that x^2 + y^2 =< n^2

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to write an algorithm in C which for a given natural number `n` would find the number of pairs `(x,y)` where `x,y` are integers such that

> x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> <= n<sup>2</sup>

I am able to do this with two for loops, however, this seems to be suboptimal. What would be the most effective approach to this problem?

Comment: Posing the "I am able to do this with two for loops" code would help clarify details of this otherwise broad question.

Comment: It would certainly be suboptimal if the inner loop begins at `0` and not `x`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: correct, although it does not change the time-complexity.

Comment: You must specify the range for `x` and `y`, can they be negative? can they be `0`?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html

Comment: @chqrlie: integers are negative and positive including 0. Integer is a quite well defined mathematical term. ONly with natural number you sometimes have the ambiguity whether it includes 0 or not

Comment: @AndreasH.: I agree with your definitions, I was asking the OP for confirmation.  There is a single solution for `n=0`. For us French oldtimers, bred on the fundamentals of Bourbaki since our early years, the set of natural numbers ℕ does include 0, but I suppose Americans still have a problem with that, probably rooted in their tradition of numbering floors starting at 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One only needs to find the points at the border, i.e. for each given x the maximal y_max s.t. x^2+y_max^2 <= n. Then the number of interesting pairs for that given x is 2*y_max+1. For x=0 we have y_max=n. For x>0 we also have to consider the pairs with -x. This results in the following code:

```
int pairCnt = 2*n+1; /* pairs (0,-n), (0,-n+1), ..., (0,n) */
int n2 = n*n;
for (int x=1; x<=n; ++x)
{
   int y_max = (int)sqrt(n2-x*x);
   pairCnt += 2*(2*y_max+1); /* (+/-x,-y_max), ..., (+/-x,y_max) */
}
```

The use of sqrt can be avoided with the following algorithm:

```
int pairCnt = 2*n+1; /* pairs (0,-n), (0,-n+1), ..., (0,n) */
int n2 = n*n;
for (int x=1, y_max=n; 1; ++x)
{
  if (y_max*y_max > n2-x*x)
    --y_max;
  if (x > y_max) break;
  pairCnt += 2*(2*y_max+1); /* (+/-x,-y_max), ..., (+/-x,y_max) */
}
int s = 2*x-1; /* side length of maximal inscribed square */
pairCnt = 2*pairCnt - s*s;
```

The first idea for the second algorithm is that when x increases y_max will decrease maximally by 1 as long as y_max>x (i.e. we go along the inner of the circle with radius n from (0,n) until we cross the first median y=x). When we add a copy of the counted points turned by 90° (i.e. double the points found so far), we will have counted the points inside the maximal inscribed square twice.

Here is a kind of visualization for n=3. `*` marks pairs outside the interesting set (`x*x+y*y > n*n=9`). Numbers mark how often pairs inside the interesting set (`x*x+y*y <= n*n=9`) have been counted so far.

```
  before loop  after loop  after doubling  result
   ----         ----         ----          ----
   432101234    432101234    432101234     432101234

 4 *********    *********    *********     *********
 3 ****1****    ****1****    ****1****     ****1****
 2 **00100**    **11111**    **22222**     **11111**
 1 **00100**    **11111**    **22222**     **11111**
 0 *0001000*    *0111110*    *1222221*     *1111111*
-1 **00100**    **11111**    **22222**     **11111**
-2 **00100**    **11111**    **22222**     **11111**
-3 ****1****    ****1****    ****1****     ****1****
-4 *********    *********    *********     *********
```

Comment: I would say "pair" refers to ordered pair, so that (0,1) is different from (1,0). I think If pair refers to unordered pair {x,y} then it really counts twice.

Comment: OK, if the pairs are ordered, so (0,1) and (1,0) count as 2 solutions.

Comment: hmm, but wait, what about entries with (i,i) and 0 < i < n. Are these counted correctly?

Comment: @AndreasH. the first algo scans from x=0 to x=n. pairs (i,i) are not special with this approach.

Comment: "One only needs to find the points at the border" --> Hmmm, With `n=65`, 4 pairs `(52:39),(56:33),(60:25),(63:16)` come up.  `(63,16)` may be  _at the border_, and `(52:39),(60:25)` may be uninteresting as they share multiples, yet (56,33,65) shares no common multiples.  Unclear on how this answer would find `x=56,y=33,n=65`

Comment: @4386427 thanks for your hint, I was a bit too quick with my edit. But now also second algo is correct

Comment: @chux with border I mean the border of the set x*x+y*y <= n, not pairs with x*x+y*y = n.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need two loops. Just loop over x, and then you can calculate `y` because both `x` and `n` are known.

Comment: Not really, he wants *all* the y's that satisfy `x^2 + y^2 <= n^2`. He will need a loop to print all those y's.

Comment: So what? x^2 + y^2 <= n^2 is basically an area inside a circle. So imagine you're iterating by x coordinate from -n to n and check if there is at least one integer y that is <= sqrt(n^2 - x^2). you can easily find how many of them you have for that particular x.

Comment: @ilim He doesn't need to print all the pairs, only to count them.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement a function `int int_sqrt (int n)`, which returns the integer part of `sqrt(double n)` ,then you could handle it with only one loop by using this function. But the integer square root exists only in C++, so you'd have to implement one in C by casting results to `int`

Edit : 
Here's the idea :

```
int x=0,result=0;
while ( (n-(x*x)) >=0){
    result += int_sqrt ( n-(x*x) ) +1;
    x++;
}
```

that's in the case you accept all integers, including 0 to make your couples.

Comment: it is a little tricky to count the number of solutions without duplicates, but I agree a single loop should suffice.

Comment: depends if (x,y) is considered different from (y,x) with x!=y, which is the case by mathematics standarts ; but that gives a hint anyways.